# AngularJS - Set a class name defined in the scope

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.05

I'd like to have something like this:

In my controller:

```
$scope.location = $location.path().split('/')[2]
$scope.lang = $routeParams.lang
$scope.bodyClassName = ((if $scope.location isnt "login" then "sub" else ""))
```

I'd like to report these variables in an document object to get for example:

```
<div class="home en sub"></div>
```

I tried with

`<div class="{{location}} {{lang}} {{bodyClassName}}"></div>`

It works on the first load but not when the view get refresh.

As the documentation says, **ng-class** is made to **evaluate** expressions, but I need to **print** a variable.

What is the good way for that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to watch the `$location.path()` to pick up route changes and update scope variables accordingly:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $location.path();
}, function(newPath) {
  $scope.location = $location.path().split('/')[2]
  $scope.lang = $routeParams.lang
  $scope.bodyClassName = ((if $scope.location isnt "login" then "sub" else ""))
});
```

and then, in your markup, as you have tried:

```
<div class="{{location}} {{lang}} {{bodyClassName}}"></div>
```

Another variation of the above is to update scope variables only on the route change success event and not in every watch.

Comment: Watching $location.path() looks like a good idea but it makes problem with $digest as it seems like a new object is created when the location changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<div class="location + ' ' + lang"></div>
```

or,

```
<div class="[ location, lang ].join(' ')"></div>
```